# I need help finding a way to ignore certain values in one of my columns in my gnu file

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to plot the secondary structure of a protein over 5000 frames using gnuplot. I have 3 columns xyz and I only need the values in the z column that are either the number 0 or 4 because those are the only things necessary for this graph. Is there a way I could exclude the other numbers 0-8 that are not 4 or 0. I have attached a screenshot of the file and a picture of the graph generated through gnuplot with all the data.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALlob.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFKLc.png)

Comment: Please don't post images of text. Just post the text.

Comment: Sorry my bad. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know exactly what kind of plot you want, but I assume it is something based on the x and y values. So for example this will plot whatever f(x,y) is for every line of data, where columns 1 2 and 3 hold x y and z. Column 0 is the line number, counting only valid lines.

```
   plot 'data' using 0 : (f($1,$2))
```

Now if you want to make the same plot but only using data lines for which z = 0 or z = 4 we modify this to

```
  plot 'data' using ( ($3==0 || $3==4) ? $0 : NaN) : (f($1,$2))
```

Comment: Hello Ethan. Yes I am trying to plot the x and y values on a plot but i only want to plot the x and y values that have either a "0" or "4" in their z column. I have 8 cbtics labeled "0-7" and I only want the cbtics that are "none" and "alpha" which correlate to z values of "0" and "4". I tried the line of code you sent, the second version, and i received an error stating that "f" is an undefined function. Do you know why this may be and where I am going wrong. Thank you for your help.

Comment: gnuplot> plot "dssp.gnu" using ( ($3==0 || $3==4) ? $0 :NaN) : (f($1,$2))
         undefined function: f

Comment: f(x,y) is whatever function you want to plot. You have to define the function yourself, since I do not know what you want to plot.

Comment: I am not sure if you would know but is there a way to find what my function is? Because what i am trying to plot is how a protein unfolds/folds over the span of 5000 frames and the z column represents the different aspects the protein but i am only looking at the "none" and "alpha" sections. So i am not sure if there is a way to check what my function is or what.

Comment: also im not sure if this changes anything but its a 3d graph with pm3d

Comment: You have not yet provided enough information for anyone to answer your question. OK a 3D graph.. so where does the x coordinate come from? where does the y coordinate come from?  What value of z do you want to plot?  Probably you want to plot z=f(x,y), but what is f()?  Nobody knows but you.